# No sound on powerpc, soundcard not detected

Tags: sound, 13.10, lubuntu, powerpc

I am running Lubuntu 13.10 on, among other machines, a Mac iBook G4.

I hear the signature sound on turning the machine on, but there is no sound when playing audio or video.

```
robert@lubuntu-ibookg4:~$  aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

I have read the advice here, and everything appears in order: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Why_do_I_have_no_sound.3F

My sound does not appear to be muted*.

Modules:

snd-powermac is loaded.

The following are blacklisted:
snd-aoa,
snd-aoa-fabric-layout,
snd-aoa-soundbus,
snd-aoa-i2sbus,
snd-aoa-codec-tas.

(* The above link gives the advice: "You need to check more than just your master volume,
for example the volume of the PCM channel maybe set to zero". However, I do not know how to
check the "PCM channel". I have installed gnome-alsamixer, but it does not appear to open properly i.e.
the GUI opens but without any controls, just a blank window).

Any help gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had failed to consider that I might have both the wrong sound module loaded AND one of the volume controls muted. Thus when I tried with the other sound modules I did not at the same time re-try with alsamixer. (Reading above, see that alsamixer would not show any controls with snd-powermac loaded).

The solution was to ensure that these modules were loaded:

```
snd-aoa
snd-aoa-fabric-layout
snd-aoa-soundbus
snd-aoa-i2sbus
snd-aoa-codec-tas
```

and this one blacklisted:

```
snd-powermac
```

i.e. the opposite of the configuration installed by default.

Details here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Why_do_I_have_no_sound.3F

How?

1. In /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local.conf comment out the blacklisted modules that are in fact required to be loaded:

   blacklist snd-aoa
   blacklist snd-aoa-fabric-layout
   blacklist snd-aoa-soundbus
   blacklist snd-aoa-i2sbus
   blacklist snd-aoa-codec-tas

and uncomment the following:

```
# blacklist snd-powermac
```

2. In /etc/modules add:

snd-aoa
snd-aoa-fabric-layout
snd-aoa-soundbus
snd-aoa-i2sbus
snd-aoa-codec-tas

Then, from a terminal I opened alsamixer, which now displayed normally. I toggled "PCM" to unmuted by selecting it and typing "m", then crucially I did the same with "Headphone". Without this last step there was still no sound, although what this has to do with it I don't know as I don't have any headphones attached.

Anyway, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this after some looking around and this corrected my no sound issues.

I have Lubuntu on a *imac g4 powerpc*.

```
su (enter root password)
nano /etc/modules
```

Add the following lines:

```
snd_aoa_i2sbus
snd_aoa_fabric_layout
snd_aoa_codec_tas
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, close terminal, reboot.

References:
http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/sound ... 47859.html
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=187&t=97450

Comment: your first link is broken